# JS Include is not working

Tags: javascript

I have moved an large piece of JS code form my header file to it's own .js file.
I'm trying to include it with:

```
<script src="includes/js/test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The JS code is not loaded, what could be wrong?

Comment: Many things could be wrong. With the information you've provided us, we can't really give you any more insight.

Comment: Can you link to the page in question, or provide more context?  There is nothing wrong with your script tag.  Make sure the file actually exists in the location specified in the `src` property, otherwise that should work.  Need more info, more context.

Comment: What happens when you type `http://your.domain/the-page/includes/js/test.js` into the browser address box?

Comment: The src url in the script tag above should be a link when you view > source the page, click it and make sure that the js file is displayed. If not, then it is a problem with the url to the file. If it is displayed, then it is probably a problem/error in the file itself. To test that, replace the contents of your js file with a simple alert('test'); and reload to see if the code is getting executed. If it is, work back from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible reason is that the path is wrong.  Remember that the path as you've written it will be interpreted relative to the current URL. So if this code appears on a page that is accessed at

http://www.example.com/example1/index.html

then the browser will request the javascript file from

```
http://www.example.com/example1/includes/js/test.js
```

which may not be what you want.  A better approach may be to use a link that is based on the root: that is, if you change it to

```
<script src="/includes/js/test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

then it will always look in

```
http://www.example.com/includes/js/test.js
```

no matter where the link appears.

Comment: I have tried it. With lots of JS codes it works. There is still one that won't work. What could be the reason? It's this code: http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/inline-modal-window-w-css-and-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess based on the information you've provided, I'd say there's probably a syntax error in the external .js file or the page isn't finding the file from the URL provided. That's usually the problem I experience when I move large pieces of code from one file to another.